# How can I Build Dynamic Breadcrumbs Component base on current Route/URL?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to build a Breadcrumbs component dynamically generating link base on my current URL

---

Ex.

```
http://localhost:8080/car/create
```

My Breadcrumbs should look like

> Home > car > create

---

Ex.

```
http://localhost:8080/car/ford
```

My Breadcrumbs should look like

> Home > car > ford

---

Ex.

```
http://localhost:8080/car/ford/raptor
```

My Breadcrumbs should look like

> Home > car > ford > raptor

How would one dynamically build sth like this ?

---

I have

```
<template lang="">
    <v-row>
            <v-breadcrumbs :items="links" class="black--text">
                <template v-slot:divider>
                    <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
                </template>
            </v-breadcrumbs>
        </v-row>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Breadcrumbs',
    props: {
        title: String
    },
    data() {
        return {
            links: [
                {
                    text: 'Home',
                    disabled: false,
                    href: '/'
                },
                {
                    text: this.title,
                    disabled: true,
                    href: 'breadcrumbs_link_2'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't tag your post titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a `computed` property like the following:

```js
const breadcrumb = Vue.component('breadcrumb', {
  template: '#breadcrumb',
  props: { title: String },
  computed: {
    links: function() {
      return [ 
        { text: 'Home', disabled: false, href: '/' }, 
        { text: this.title, disabled: true, href: 'breadcrumbs_link_2' },
        ...(
          (new URL(window.location.href))
            .pathname
            .split('/')
            .slice(1)
            .map(seg => ({ text: seg, disabled: false, href: seg }))
        )
      ]; 
    }
  }
});

new Vue({ el:"#app", vuetify: new Vuetify(), components: { breadcrumb } });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<template id="breadcrumb">
  <v-row>
    <v-breadcrumbs :items="links" class="black--text">
      <template v-slot:divider><v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon></template>
    </v-breadcrumbs>
  </v-row>
</template>

<v-app id="app">
  <breadcrumb title="title_1" />
</v-app>
```

Comment: Dude … you are like my Vuejs hero

Comment: Haha glad to help, it has been a while since I used vue so thanks for the interesting problems :)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/3VJwvhs.png

Comment: I seems to add an extra `>` `>` icon. I don't know what caused it.

Comment: Isn't this the title prop? You had second element where it's the text. If you only want home, and then the dynamic part, then remove the second object in the computed property result

Comment: Let me try that .. thank-you.

Comment: What line do I need to remove ? I'm still new to the vuejs syntax. https://i.imgur.com/68uP1GS.png

Comment: Ah I got it. I commented out line 18:.

Answer (score 1):

This solution gives you the ability to customize the text on the crumbs via the vue router(other than relying on the path text which may not always be sufficient) and also allow to even capture url parameters.

in your router.js add an extra property to each object

```
{
          path: "bank-statement",
          component: StorageAccountList,
          name: "storage-accounts",
          meta: {
            title: "Bank Accounts ",
            resource: "bankAccounts",
            breadCrumb: "Bank & Cash accounts"
          }
        },
```

then in your computed of the main component that houses all others, add this

```
<v-breadcrumbs
        style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0;"
        :items="crumbs"
      >
        <template v-slot:divider>
          <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
        </template>
      </v-breadcrumbs>

computed: {
    
    crumbs: function() {
      let pathArray = this.$route.path.split("/");
      pathArray.shift();
      let itemsCount = pathArray.length;

      return pathArray.reduce((breadcrumbArray, path, idx) => {
        let count = idx + 2;
        breadcrumbArray.push({
          // to: {path:idx>1 ? "/" + breadcrumbArray[idx - 1].path + "/" : "/"+path },
          path: path,
          disabled: count > itemsCount,
          href: breadcrumbArray[idx - 1]
            ? "/" + breadcrumbArray[idx - 1].path + "/" + path
            : "/" + path,
          text:
            (this.$route.matched[idx] &&
              this.$route.matched[idx].meta.breadCrumb) ||
            path
        });
        return breadcrumbArray;
      }, []);
    }
  },
```